# Store a base64 image in mongodb using ReactiveGridFsTemplate Spring Webflux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-mongodb

Previously, i was able to store a **base64** image using **GridFsTemplate** as below.

```
val imageBytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("base64 image string")
gridFsTemplate.store(ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes), "imagename")
```

However the **store()** function of **ReactiveGridFsTemplate** takes in a parameter which is of type `Flux<DataBuffer>`. How can i convert a base64 image to that type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use AsyncStreamHelper.toAsyncInputStream with the base64 as a byte array.

I'm on my phone right now so I can't write an example, but you can check the second last method of the class here: https://github.com/BayviewComputerClub/smoothie-web/blob/master/src/main/java/club/bayview/smoothieweb/repositories/TestDataRepository.java